# Reading and writing byte-by-byte for compression

Tags: python, binary, hex

I am trying to implement the Lempel-Ziv-Welch algorithm with python, but am having trouble writing my file in binary.

```
action = sys.argv[3]
if action == "compress":
# initialize dictionary
dictionary = {}
for i in range(0,256):
    # for single characters, the value is the same as the key
    # in the compressed file, these would appear as is
    dictionary[chr(i)] = i 
input_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb+')
output_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')

data = input_file.read()
# current_data is one byte
current_data = input_file.read(1)
i = 0
j = 1
current_data = data[i:j]
# look for the shortest string not in the dictionary
while i < len(data) - 2:
    while current_data in dictionary.keys():
        if j < len(data) + 1:
            j = j + 1
            current_data = data[i:j]
        else:
            break
    # once the shortest string is found, add it to the dictionary 
    if current_data not in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[current_data] = len(dictionary)
        thing_to_write = dictionary[current_data[:-1]]
        i = j - 1
        current_data = data[i:j]
    else:
        thing_to_write = dictionary[current_data]
        i = i + 1
        j = i + 1
    # then write to the output file the found string - one character from the end (the longest string that is in the dictionary)\
    mylist = []
    thing_to_write = format(thing_to_write,'x')
    thing_to_write = thing_to_write
    for char in thing_to_write:
        mylist.append(char.encode('hex'))
        for elem in mylist:
            output_file.write(elem)
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
print >> sys.stderr, "The size of " + sys.argv[1] + " is " + str(os.path.getsize(sys.argv[1])) + " bytes." + "\n" + "The size of " + sys.argv[2] + " is " + str(os.path.getsize(sys.argv[2])) + " bytes."
```

I've tried writing in so many different formats, like hex, binary, etc, but I think I am just writing them as 8 bit characters. How can I write in raw binary?

Comment: what means "I am having trouble" ? Do you get error message ? Then add full message to question.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to write. The data you are getting can end up being greater than 256 so I am assuming you are wanting to write 2 byte unsigned integers to your output file?

If this is the case then I suggest you investigate Python's [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct.pack#struct.pack) function which is designed to convert data from Python's types into binary representations. If your data had been byte sized, you could have just used `output_file.write(chr(x))` to write each character.

The following uses Python's `struct.pack()`:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import sys
import struct

action = sys.argv[3]

if action == "compress":
    # initialize dictionary
    dictionary = {}

for i in range(0,256):
    # for single characters, the value is the same as the key
    # in the compressed file, these would appear as is
    dictionary[chr(i)] = i 

input_file = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
output_file = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')

data = input_file.read()

# current_data is one byte
current_data = input_file.read(1)
i = 0
j = 1
current_data = data[i:j]

# look for the shortest string not in the dictionary

while i < len(data) - 2:
    while current_data in dictionary.keys():
        if j < len(data) + 1:
            j = j + 1
            current_data = data[i:j]
        else:
            break

    # once the shortest string is found, add it to the dictionary 
    if current_data not in dictionary.keys():
        dictionary[current_data] = len(dictionary)
        thing_to_write = dictionary[current_data[:-1]]
        i = j - 1
        current_data = data[i:j]
    else:
        thing_to_write = dictionary[current_data]
        i = i + 1
        j = i + 1

    # then write to the output file the found string - one character from the end (the longest string that is in the dictionary)\
    output_file.write(struct.pack('H', thing_to_write))     # Convert each thing into 2 byte binary

input_file.close()
output_file.close()

print >> sys.stderr, "The size of " + sys.argv[1] + " is " + str(os.path.getsize(sys.argv[1])) + " bytes." + "\n" + "The size of " + sys.argv[2] + " is " + str(os.path.getsize(sys.argv[2])) + " bytes."
```